# Manipulate command query string to return 1 COUNT clause?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, ibm-midrange

I've created a winforms application that allows users to set their criteria, query ibm 400 system, view results, then mail merge selected results. As an extra feature, I'm trying to set a label that will tell users upon criteria selection (searching via code, not them clicking Search) how many records have been printed out of total results for given criteria.

**Example: 30 of 35 printed.**

This means 30 documents have been marked in tracking table as printed out of 35 total.

Currently I am working on the total record count of that string, not the "how many printed" portion. So currently, my code is setting the label as "# of" + **RecCount** + " printed.".

I'm running into some issues though. Users have their choice of 3 data sources: **System1**, **System2**, and **BOTH**.

The following details my queries and the results:

**CRITERIA**: 20121209, System1, ALL RECORDS, OLD ADDR

**QUERY**: SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount FROM Library2.Table1 a, Library2.Table2 b WHERE a.memno = b.memno and b.groupid = 'N2' and b.type = 'B' and b.datec = 20131209 AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip)

### **RETURNED CNT**: 24

**CRITERIA**: 20121209, System2, ALL RECORDS, OLD ADDR

**QUERY**: SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount FROM psrslib.pai000pf a, psrslib.pch010pf b WHERE a.memno = b.memno and b.groupid = 'PAI0002' and b.type = 'B' and b.datec = 20131209 AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip)

### **RETURNED CNT**: 14

These 2 above seem to be functioning appropriately. But when I come to the BOTH datasource:

**CRITERIA**: 20121209, BOTH, ALL RECORDS, OLD ADDR

**QUERY**: SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount FROM psrslib.pai000pf a, psrslib.pch010pf b WHERE a.memno = b.memno and b.groupid = 'PAI0002' and b.type = 'B' and b.datec = 20131209 AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount FROM ntrslib.nai000pf a, ntrslib.nch010pf b WHERE a.memno = b.memno and b.groupid = 'NAI0002' and b.type = 'B' and b.datec = 20131209 AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip)

### **RETURNED CNT**: 24 -- *// This should be 38*

Upon inspecting my code and using server explorer I found the following:

My original Search Query **before** string manipulation to only receive the Count:

```
SELECT a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
b.timec 

FROM Library1.Table1 a, Libary1.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'P2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131209 
AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) 

UNION SELECT a.memno, 
a.name, 
a.addr1, 
a.addr2, 
a.city, 
a.state, 
a.zip, 
a.sex, 
a.lname, 
a.ssan, 
b.addr1 as old_addr1, 
b.addr2 as old_addr2, 
b.city as old_city, 
b.state as old_state, 
b.zip as old_zip, 
b.timec 

FROM Library2.Table1 a, Library2.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'N2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131209 
AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) 

ORDER BY timec desc
```

My Code:

```
    private void getNumPrinted()
            {
                string qryCmd = "";
                OdbcDataReader dr;

                if (cnt > 1)
                {
                    switch (cmbLetterType.SelectedIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            docType = "oldAddr";
                            qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            docType = "newAddr";
                            qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            docType = "nameChg";
                            qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                            break;
                    }

                    string query = "";

                    if (qryCmd.Contains("INNER JOIN"))
                    {
                        var newQry = qryCmd.Replace(qryCmd.Substring(0, qryCmd.IndexOf("FROM TableC c") - 1), "SELECT COUNT(a.memno) AS RecCount");
                        var orderByIndex = newQry.IndexOf("ORDER BY");
                        newQry = newQry.Replace(newQry.Substring(orderByIndex, newQry.Length - orderByIndex), "");
                        query = newQry;


   }
                else
                {
                    var newQry = qryCmd.Replace(qryCmd.Substring(0, qryCmd.IndexOf("FROM") - 1), "SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount");
                    var orderByIndex = newQry.IndexOf("ORDER BY");
                    newQry = newQry.Replace(newQry.Substring(orderByIndex, newQry.Length - orderByIndex), "");
                    query = newQry;
                }

                dr = mdl.GetData(query);
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    lblNumPrinted.Text = "# out of " + dr["RecCount"].ToString() + " printed";
                }

                // NEED TO PERFORM ANOTHER QUERY COMBINED WITH TableC to see how many records have not been printed.

                mdl.closeConn();
                lblNumPrinted.Visible = true;
            }
            cnt++;
        }
```

After String Manipulation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount 
FROM Library1.Table1 a, Library1.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'P2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131209 
AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip) 

UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount 
FROM Library2.Table1 a, Library2.Table2 b 
WHERE a.memno = b.memno and 
b.groupid = 'N2' and 
b.type = 'B' and 
b.datec = 20131209 
AND (a.addr1 <> b.addr1 or a.addr2 <> b.addr2 or a.city <> b.city or a. state <> b.state or a.zip <> b.zip)
```

I could not figure out as mentioned why my above query after string manipulation was setting the label to a value of "*# of **24** printed.*"

When I ran my query in Server Explorer however, I saw the issue. In code I am trying to receive a single COUNT, and my replace code line is changing both select clauses in the UNION to the new "**SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount**".

Server Explorer Results:

[RecCount]

[14]

[24]

Can someone show me what modification I need to do to my code/query that uses the BOTH datasource so that I receive a single `RecCount` of 38?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your existing pair of queries inside a common table expression and use that as the source that you want to total up.

```
with counts as (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount 
FROM Library1.Table1 a, Library1.Table2 b 
WHERE... 
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecCount 
FROM Library2.Table1 a, Library2.Table2 b 
WHERE...
)
select sum(RecCount) from counts;
```

Comment: I like your idea Buck. Any suggestions for how to modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: I talked my way in, through, and around several different ordeals, but I finally was able to implement your solution by simplay adding the `with couts as (` at the start of my modified query and `) select sum(recCount) from counts` at the end before executing the query. Thanks buck. I'll probably be back around soon trying to query for records not yet printed by combining with my TableC and checking the PRINT_OLD value for NULL

Comment: Normally I'd make these SQL statements into stored procedures rather than construct (and scan/replace) them in code.  Then have the code call the proper stored procedure.  If you're tied to the scan/replace paradigm, concatenate the 'with counts as(' at the front of newQry and append ') select count(*) from counts' at the end.